# How to select count of records exist in table also exist in table b?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
tableA

id    a_id     b_id
1     100      200
2     101      201
3     100      202


tableB

id    a_id     b_id
2     100      200
3     201      101
4     203      100
```

so I want to get the count of `a_id=100` but except the one also exist in tableB

so

```
in tableA i got 2:
    1     100      200
    3     100      202
```

but `100/200` exists in tableB, so result is 1

How to write the sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT      COUNT(1)
FROM        TableA AS A
WHERE       NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT    NULL
                            FROM      TableB AS B
                            WHERE     B.a_id = A.a_id
                                  AND B.b_id = A.b_id
                       )
       AND A.a_id = 100
```

If you want to do it with `left join`:

```
SELECT      COUNT(1) 
FROM        TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN   TableB AS B
        ON  B.a_id = A.a_id
        AND B.b_id = A.b_id
WHERE       B.a_id IS NULL
        AND A.a_id = 100
```

Comment: is it possible to use join?

Comment: The join will match all similar rows, if a row in TableA can't be matched by a row in TableB, the B values are left null. Those are the ones we want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tableA a
WHERE a_id = 100 AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tableB b
  WHERE b.a_id = a.a_id AND b.b_id = a.b_id
)
```